# SSRS User set up with full permissions, but receiving the rsAccessDenied error saying user does not have sufficient privileges. Why is this?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have been using SSRS and Report Builder for a while and have set up a new user to access the reports and make edits. They have been given System Administrator rights in Site Settings security, and confirmed they have Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder roles on the folder management screen.

They also have the same SQL server permimissions as myself (who can access everything).

They can navigate to the URL through the browser and see the files and folders by going to http://SERVER/Reports/browse/REPORTS_FOLDER, but can't access the URL http://SERVER/ReportServer that Report Builder wants to connect to. They get:

> The permissions granted to user 'USER' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

I'm at the end of my troubleshooting expertise really so hoping for some help!

I've given all possible permissions through the SSRS browser URL on all folders, also the exact same permissions on the SQL server instance that I have.

I've played with the browser Trusted Sites and Local Sites setting which hasn't worked, and have run Report Builder as Administrator which hasn't worked either. However if I run it with my credentials it works fine.

Comment: If you check the `Users` table in the ReportServer database do they have old/multiple accounts with the same username but a different SID?

Comment: No, there are no other accounts with the same UserName or SID/UserID.

Comment: At what point does the user get the error, when trying to connect to the report server via Report Builder?

Comment: The user can open Report Builder through the browser file (i.e. clicking 'Open in Report Builder'). Which connects to the SQL server we're using without issue. But if they then go to either 'Open' or 'Save As' within RB, and selects 'Recent Sites and Servers' they can see the correct server, but when clicking on it the error appears.